# Ant: Is it possible to replace command line options with build.xml attributes?

Tags: ant

I am trying to add a typedef for fortify as specified [here](http://flylib.com/books/en/2.845.1.117/1/). Everything works if I call ant like this ("fortify" is the name of my build target:

```
ant -lib /Applications/HP_Fortify/HP_Fortify_SCA_and_Apps_4.10/Core/lib/
sourceanalyzer.jar -Dsourceanalyzer.buildid=MyBuild  fortify
```

I would like to just call

```
ant fortify
```

Unfortunately when I do I get two errors. The first is that sourceanalyzer.buildid must be defined, even though I defined it like this:

```
<property name="sourceanalyzer.buildid" value="MyBuild"/>
```

The second is

> typedef class `com.fortify.dev.ant.SourceanalyzerTask` cannot be found using the classloader `AntClassLoader[]`.

So I suppose this is really two questions:

1. Any ideas why my property might not be recognized? It's well before it's used.
2. Is it possible to replace the -lib command line option with something in the build.xml file prior to the typedef?

Comment: For the first point are you sure the `property` task call is being reached in the buildfile and before using it? [Echoing](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/echo.html) the property value might help.

Comment: @Ginger McMurray... Am facing the same issue. Are you able to integrate fortify scanning with ant buid ?

Comment: @Krupa, unfortunately we ran out of time on that project and resorted to running fortify manually.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this to replace the "-lib" parameter:

```
<path id="task.path">
  <pathelement location="/Applications/HP_Fortify/HP_Fortify_SCA_and_Apps_4.10/Core/lib/sourceanalyzer.jar"/> 
</path>

<typedef name="fortify" classname="com.fortify.dev.ant.SourceanalyzerTask" classpathref="task.path"/>
```